# Apply a function to the nth element of a list

Tags: haskell

I need to be able to apply a function to the nth element of a list. For example:

```
> doSomething (+5) 2 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

should return `[1,7,3,4,5]`

I have a function that can do this:

```
doSomething :: (a -> a) -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
doSomething f n xs = ys ++ [f x] ++ zs
    where (ys, x:zs) = splitAt (n - 1) xs
```

but I'm new to Haskell, and so I'm sure (as with many simple functions in Haskell) there is a much better way of doing this.

Comment: Take a look at lenses.

Comment: Taking a look at lenses may not be the best idea for somebody new to Haskell. I think that what you have here is fine. Are you looking for something more efficient? More idiomatic? A one-liner?

Comment: @jamshidh I had a quick look at lenses, but I would prefer to be able to do this without any packages yet.

Comment: @AlexanderVieth Are those options mutually exclusive? It's just, in my limited experience with Haskell, the approach a beginner takes is usually the '_wrong_' approach for Haskell.

Comment: No they are not mutually exclusive, just wondering what your goal is. `doSomething` is certainly correct, and I could understand it very quickly, so I see nothing 'wrong' with it except for performance considerations (++ is potentially slow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to dive into lenses, and prefer a simple solution, you can just use list comprehensions; it runs on linear time, your list concatenations would degrade performance on large lists:

```
Prelude> [if i == 2 then v + 5 else v | (i, v) <- zip [1..] l]
[1,7,3,4,5]
```

So, `doSomething` would be:

```
Prelude> let doSomething f i l = [if p == i then f v else v | (p, v) <- zip [1..] l]
Prelude> doSomething (+5) 2 [1,2,3,4,5]
[1,7,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Should it not be `if p == i then f v else v`?
Apart from that, this the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

As jamshidh indicates the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package makes it simple to achieve this kind of task.

```
> import Control.Lens.Combinators
> over (element 2) (+5) [1..5]
[1,2,8,4,5]
```

This kind of operation works over any traversable, for example trees:

```
> import Data.Tree
> let tree = Node 1 [Node 2 [], Node 3 []]
> putStr . drawTree . fmap show $ tree
1
|
+- 2
|
`- 3
> putStr . drawTree . fmap show $ over (element 2) (+5) tree
1
|
+- 2
|
`- 8
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need random access to elements of a sequence, you may not want to use a list at all.  You could, for example, use [`Data.Vector`](https://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2014.2.0.0/platform/lib/vector-0.10.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html) instead:

```
import Data.Vector (Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector as V

modifyNth :: Int -> (a -> a) -> Vector a -> Vector a
modifyNth n f = V.imap f'
    where f' i a | i == n    = f a
                 | otherwise = a
```

Example use:

```
>>> modifyNth 2 (+5) (V.fromList [1,2,3,4,5])
fromList [1,2,8,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with some manual recursion pretty easily, and it will perform better than the `splitAt` version, as well as allocating fewer temporary objects than the list comprehension.

```
doSomething :: (a -> a) -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
doSomething _f _ [] = []
doSomething f 0 (x:xs) = f x : xs
doSomething f n (x:xs) = x : doSomething f (n - 1) xs
```

The cases are all pretty obvious: if the list is empty, you can't do anything, so return it. If n is 0, then just call f on it and add that to the rest of the list. Otherwise, you can 
put the current x at the front, and recurse with a smaller n.